# Using the deep neural network package "Chainer" to train a simple dataset

Tags: neural-network, training-data, chainer

I'm trying to use the chainer package for a large project I'm working on. I have read through the tutorial on their website which gives an example of applying it to the MNIST dataset, but it doesn't seem to scale easily to other examples, and there's simply not enough documentation otherwise.

Their example code is as follows:

```python
class MLP(Chain):
    def __init__(self, n_units, n_out):
        super(MLP, self).__init__(
            # the size of the inputs to each layer will be inferred
            l1=L.Linear(None, n_units),  # n_in -> n_units
            l2=L.Linear(None, n_units),  # n_units -> n_units
            l3=L.Linear(None, n_out),    # n_units -> n_out
        )

    def __call__(self, x):
        h1 = F.relu(self.l1(x))
        h2 = F.relu(self.l2(h1))
        y = self.l3(h2)
        return y

train, test = datasets.get_mnist()
train_iter = iterators.SerialIterator(train, batch_size=5, shuffle=True)
test_iter = iterators.SerialIterator(test, batch_size=2, repeat=False, shuffle=False)
model = L.Classifier(MLP(100, 10))  # the input size, 784, is inferred
optimizer = optimizers.SGD()
optimizer.setup(model)
updater = training.StandardUpdater(train_iter, optimizer)
trainer = training.Trainer(updater, (4, 'epoch'), out='result')
trainer.extend(extensions.Evaluator(test_iter, model))
trainer.extend(extensions.LogReport())
trainer.extend(extensions.PrintReport(['epoch', 'main/accuracy', 'validation/main/accuracy']))
trainer.extend(extensions.ProgressBar())
trainer.run()
```

Could someone point me in the direction of how to simple fit a straight line to a few data points in 2D? If I can understand a simple fit such as this I should be able to scale appropriately.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have a cost function based on smallest euclidean distance

Comment: I understand how to do it mathematically, my question is more focused on how to do it specifically with the chainer package.

Answer (score 0):

I pasted simple regression modeling here.

You can use original train data and test data as tuple.
    train = (data, label)

Here, data.shape = (Number of data, Number of data dimesion)

And, label.shape = (Number of data,)

Both of their data type should be numpy.float32.

```python
import chainer
from chainer.functions import *
from chainer.links import *
from chainer.optimizers import *

from chainer import training
from chainer.training import extensions
from chainer import reporter
from chainer import datasets
import numpy


class MyNet(chainer.Chain):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyNet, self).__init__(
            l0=Linear(None, 30, nobias=True),
            l1=Linear(None, 1, nobias=True),
        )

    def __call__(self, x, t):
        l0 = self.l0(x)
        f0 = relu(l0)
        l1 = self.l1(f0)
        f1 = flatten(l1)
        self.loss = mean_squared_error(f1, t)
        reporter.report({'loss': self.loss}, self)
        return self.loss


def get_optimizer():
    return Adam()


def training_main():
    model = MyNet()

    optimizer = get_optimizer()
    optimizer.setup(model)

    train, test = datasets.get_mnist(label_dtype=numpy.float32)
    train_iter = chainer.iterators.SerialIterator(train, 50)
    test_iter = chainer.iterators.SerialIterator(test, 50,
                                                 repeat=False,
                                                 shuffle=False)

    updater = training.StandardUpdater(train_iter, optimizer)
    trainer = training.Trainer(updater, (10, 'epoch'))
    trainer.extend(extensions.ProgressBar())
    trainer.extend(extensions.Evaluator(test_iter, model))
    trainer.extend(
        extensions.PlotReport(['main/loss', 'validation/main/loss'],
                              'epoch'))
    trainer.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    training_main()
```